# How to pass html element reference via .change trigger

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, onchange, eventtrigger

I have a function named showStuff() that I want called once during init and again when a select field changes. I need to pass a class or id name to the function but this won't work:

```
$('.filterChange').change($('#htmlElement'), showStuff);
```

What am I doing wrong? workaround is to call a generic function on change and from there call the showStuff() but I don't understand why the change trigger doesn't work. Same issue with .bind trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass that as an Map as that is the accepted syntax.

```
$('.filterChange').change({'myelement': $('#htmlElement')}, showStuff);

function showStuff(e) {
   $(e.data.myelement.show());
}
```

---

I think what you want is a simple inner function like below,

```
$('.filterChange').change(function () {
   showStuff($('#htmlElement'));
}).change(); //trigger during init or simply call showStuff($('#htmlElement'))
```

Comment: Should have thought of that myself! Thanks, any idea why it doesn't work like it was, considering that passing simple text works fine?

Comment: Do you mean `.change($('#htmlElement'), showStuff);`? You need to pass args like as in Rene Koch answer below. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/cg9ya/

Comment: So basically I can't pass directly(without inner function) with .change? below answer(argument passing part of it) didn't work with .change trigger.

Comment: @DominicM Yes.. but that is how you need to pass the args to the handler functions.. Also you can pass object in that case.. see updated post. http://jsfiddle.net/cg9ya/1/

Answer (score 3):

Heres the basic on how to pass data to an event:

```
function greet(event) { alert("Hello "+event.data.name); }
$("button").on("click", { name: "Karl" }, greet);
$("button").on("click", { name: "Addy" }, greet);
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/